# I want whole model return I have 2 models by using pg search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg-search

1. I want this form

   "data": [
   {
   "id": 2,
   "searchable_type": "User",
   "email": "abc",
   "first_name": "abc",
   "last_name": "xyz",
   "created_at": "2022-08-05T09:40:18.986Z",
   "updated_at": "2022-08-05T09:40:18.986Z"
   },
   {
   "id": 3,
   "searchable_type": "blog",
   "tittle": "user",
   "created_at": "2022-08-05T09:40:18.986Z",
   "updated_at": "2022-08-05T09:40:18.986Z"
   }
   ]

I want to return whole object for each model respectively by using Pg Search multi search it just return a content ,searchable_type and searchable_id as attached images below[It is my postman image for blog return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j0GI.png)[It is my postman image for user return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AaiW.png)
[*My search controller, User and blog models*]

```
class Api::V1::SearchController < Api::V1::ApiController
  def index
    @query = params[:value]
    @results = PgSearch.multisearch(@query)
    render json: { data: @results}, status: :ok
  end
end


class Blog < ApplicationRecord
 include PgSearch::Model
 multisearchable against: [:id, :title, :created_at, :updated_at ]
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch::Model
  multisearchable against: [:id, :email, :first_name, :last_name ]
end
```

Comment: `serial_no` is not in `Blog` or `User`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@results = PgSearch.multisearch(@query)
```

to

```
@results = PgSearch.multisearch(@query).includes(:searchable).map(&:searchable)
```